# How to define a variable with random values in Smarty

Tags: html, smarty

I need to assign a variable which will be used to create the id label for some html elements.

And it needs to be unique.

I tried

```
{assign var=unique_id value=`10|mt_rand:20`}
```

and

```
{math equation='rand(10,100)'}
```

But I don't know how to use the result

I don't have any other ideas

Answer (score 24, accepted):

this is how you set and use a random value but that deoesn't mean it will be unique.

```
    {assign var=unique_id value=10|mt_rand:20}
    {$unique_id}
```

can you describe a bigger picture of what your doing ?

Comment: this was used to add some randomness to some id names

Comment: Update PHP 8.2 PHP Deprecated: Using php-function "mt_rand" as a modifier is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use Smarty::registerPlugin to explicitly register a custom modifier

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an little Smarty plugin some years ago: https://www.markus.zierhut.name/2010/05/21/php-mit-smarty-zufallszahl-erzeugen/

It's a bit easier to use than handling with `mt_rand` inside the `assign`-function. And it keeps compatible with the split of Model and View.